# python data frame for fliter

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
def near (msg):
    if df['Event_step'].str.contains('nearmiss'):
        bloon = df['Event_step'].str.contains(msg)   
        filter_data = df[bloon] 
        return 'NearMiss:'+msg,len(filter_data) 
    else:   
        bloon = df['Event_step'].str.contains(msg)   
        filter_data = df[bloon]                                                
        return msg,len(filter_data)
```

And then, when I run it that I got :

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I don't know why I can not filte what I want.

Comment: Can you set a better title for your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df['Event_step'].str.contains('nearmiss')` returns a series. If requires a bool. either use `all` or `any` as a combination. like `df['Event_step'].str.contains('nearmiss').all()` or `df['Event_step'].str.contains('nearmiss').any()`

Comment: After I run it that show:During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    KeyError: False

Comment: you only need to change it in if clause. Nowhere else. ```if df['Event_step'].str.contains('nearmiss').all():```

Comment: Thank god! This problem confuses me for a long time. Now, it is addressed.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already stated in the comments:
The `contains`- function returns a boolean Series as shown below.

```
names = {"names":["a","b", "c", "d", "e"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(names)
df.names.str.contains("a")
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
False
False
```

If you want to transform this Series - Object into a scalar - boolean value like you're used to work with, then you can use the `any` - function in this case.

```
names = {"names":["a","b", "c", "d", "e"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(names)
df.names.str.contains("a").any()
```

Output:

```
True
```